# Application of Schauder's fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove the existence of a continuous function $f$ on $I = [0, 1]$ which satisfies the equation $f(x) = \int_0^1 sin (x +f^2(t)) dt$

Schauder's Fixed Point Theorem:
Suppose $K$ is a compact set in a Frechet space $X$ and $f: X \rightarrow K$ is continuous then there is a fixed point of $f$ in $K$

Comment: Equip $ X = C([0,1];\mathbb{R}) $ with the topology induced by the uniform norm, and define a map $ T: X \to X $ by
$$
\forall f \in X: \qquad
T(f) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\left\{ \begin{matrix}
[0,1] & \to & \mathbb{R} \\
x & \mapsto &
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \sin \! \left( x + [f(t)]^{2} \right) \mathrm{d}{t}
\end{matrix} \right\}.
$$
By the angle-addition formula for the sine function, $ T $ is continuous and $ \text{Range}(T) $ is equicontinuous. As $ \text{Range}(T) $ is pointwise-bounded, the Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem says that $ \text{Range}(T) $ is a compact subset of $ X $.

Comment: I am struggling with proving that $T$ is continuous.  I have, 
$||T(f) - T(g)|| \leq \int_0^1 2 sin((f^2(t) - g^2(t))/2) dt$ how to proceed? 

Also, closure of Range($T$) would be the set which is compact by Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem, right?

Comment: Let $ \epsilon > 0 $. Then there is a $ \delta > 0 $ such that $ \left| \sin \! \left( \dfrac{x}{2} \right) \right| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} $ for all $ x \in (- \delta,\delta) $. Now, fix any $ f \in X $ and consider the following intersection of two open balls in $ X $:
$$
\mathcal{O} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
{\mathbb{B}_{X}}(0_{X};\| f \|_{\infty} + 1) \cap
\mathbb{B}_{X} \! \left( f;\frac{\delta}{2 \| f \|_{\infty} + 1} \right).
$$
This is an open neighborhood of $ f $ in $ X $. Then for all $ g \in \mathcal{O} $, we have $ \| f^{2} - g^{2} \|_{\infty} < \delta $, so we are done.

Comment: The answer to your second question is ‘yes’. I forgot to include the closure for $ \text{Range}(T) $ in my first comment.